# Find the general solution for the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find the general solution of sequence $\{a_n\}$ where $a_1=5$ and $$\frac{1}{n}a_{n+1}=a_n^2+2n.$$

I was able to figure out the solution for $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}a_{n+1}=a_n^2$, which is
$$a_n = 5^{2^{n-1}}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{2^{n-1-i}},$$because

\begin{align*}
na_n^2&=5^{2^n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{2^{n-1-i}} \right)^2 \cdot n        \\
&=5^{2^n}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{2^{n-i}}\cdot n^{2^0}       \\
&=5^{2^n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}i^{2^{n-i}} \\
&= a_{n+1}       \\
\end{align*}

But I have no clue whether this is helpful for the original problem (with $+2n$).

Comment: I don't know if this should be a comment or an answer, if someone points me to the right place and it's not this, I'll correct it. Returning to the problem, using symbolic calculus Mathematica one can calculate the first few terms of the sequence and then using https://oeis.org/ seems to find no pattern, so I don't think we can find an elementary form. What's the context for this problem? What's the background?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got this problem from my friend who doesn't know the original source either, so I agree there may be no answer of elementary form. But wondering if there's any trick or strategy that can be helpful for such type of questions, not necessarily this one.